# How to run the same MATLAB code on all the GPU threads

Tags: multithreading, matlab, gpu, ode, runge-kutta

So I am writing this Runge-Kutta solver for ODEs, which takes initial conditions and returns 2 arrays. I want to run it on a wide spectrum of random initial conditions but the run time is taking forever, so I tried to setup a parfor loop as such:

```
tic
parfor i = 1:10
    [y,py] = RK(rand,rand,rand,rand);
end
toc
```

where I saw about 80% improvement of speed. Now how do I do the same but instead of CPU threads, I go for GPU threads?

Here is the whole code:

```
function [y,py] = RK(x1,y1,px1,py1)
%setting time
Time = 100;
dt = 0.01;
N = floor(Time/dt);

%Equations
f1 = @(x,y,px,py) px;
f2 = @(x,y,px,py) py;
f3 = @(x,y,px,py) -x -2*x*y;
f4 = @(x,y,px,py) -y -x^2 + y^2;

%Initializing the matrix that will store the values of the weights
c = zeros(4,4);
x = zeros(1,N);
y = zeros(1,N);
px = zeros(1,N);
py = zeros(1,N);

x(1) = x1; y(1) = y1; px(1) = px1; py(1) = py1;

for i = 1:N-1
    c(1,1) = dt*f1(x(i),y(i),px(i),py(i));
    c(2,1) = dt*f2(x(i),y(i),px(i),py(i));
    c(3,1) = dt*f3(x(i),y(i),px(i),py(i));
    c(4,1) = dt*f4(x(i),y(i),px(i),py(i));

    c(1,2) = dt*f1(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,1),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,1),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,1),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,1));
    c(2,2) = dt*f2(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,1),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,1),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,1),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,1));
    c(3,2) = dt*f3(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,1),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,1),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,1),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,1));
    c(4,2) = dt*f4(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,1),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,1),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,1),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,1));

    c(1,3) = dt*f1(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,2),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,2),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,2),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,2));
    c(2,3) = dt*f2(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,2),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,2),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,2),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,2));
    c(3,3) = dt*f3(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,2),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,2),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,2),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,2));
    c(4,3) = dt*f4(x(i) + 0.5*c(1,2),y(i) + 0.5*c(2,2),px(i) + 0.5*c(3,2),py(i) + 0.5*c(4,2));

    c(1,4) = dt*f1(x(i) + c(1,3),y(i) + c(2,3),px(i) + c(3,3),py(i) + c(4,3));
    c(2,4) = dt*f2(x(i) + c(1,3),y(i) + c(2,3),px(i) + c(3,3),py(i) + c(4,3));
    c(3,4) = dt*f3(x(i) + c(1,3),y(i) + c(2,3),px(i) + c(3,3),py(i) + c(4,3));
    c(4,4) = dt*f4(x(i) + c(1,3),y(i) + c(2,3),px(i) + c(3,3),py(i) + c(4,3));

    x(i+1) = x(i) + (1/6)*(c(1,1) + 2*c(1,2) + 2*c(1,3) +c(1,4));
    y(i+1) = y(i) + (1/6)*(c(2,1) + 2*c(2,2) + 2*c(2,3) +c(2,4));
    px(i+1) = px(i) + (1/6)*(c(3,1) + 2*c(3,2) + 2*c(3,3) +c(3,4));
    py(i+1) = py(i) + (1/6)*(c(4,1) + 2*c(4,2) + 2*c(4,3) +c(4,4));
end

zer = find(x<0.00001 & x>-0.00001);
y = y(zer);
py = py(zer);
end
```

Comment: Have yor tried using `gpuArray`? By the way, i suspect the code to be much slower on a gpu. From what I see, you are only using scalar operations, no matrix or vector operations.

Comment: I tried to transform all the arrays to gpuArrays, then I tried the same and removed function handles, but to no avail.

Comment: Not all operations can be sped up using the GPU. This is one of those.

Comment: What does no avail mean? Slower code? That is what I would expect.

Comment: Perhaps your best option is to try the `gpuArray` version of `arrayfun`. https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/gpuarray.arrayfun.html . This is useful when you have a large number of identical scalar operations to perform. You might well need to restructure your code quite a bit though - I think you'd need to make each arrayfun call perform one time-step of your ODE. This may or may not turn out to give you decent performance...